# Using :CocSearch for pattern with backslashes

Tags: coc.nvim

How do I do a search through `:CocSearch` for anything containing backslashes?

i.e: `Module\Auth`

Comment: Try escaping the backslash with the second backslash: `Module\\Auth`

Comment: Doesn't work with it

Answer (score 1):

Turns out `:CocSearch` uses ripgrep (rg), so I applied the option `--fixed-strings` (-F) and the search string without quotes and it worked:

`CocSearch -F Module\Auth`